# Is there any way to use if condition in github actions such that use WITH VARIABLES based on platform

Tags: if-statement, github-actions

Let's say I want to login to quay.io in linux/amd64 and docker.io in linux/arm64 in github actions. Is there any way to do this in github actions to add the condition?

```
- uses: docker/login-action@v2
  if: CONDITION_TO_USE LIKE BASED ON PLATFORM USE DIFFERENT REGISTRY FOR EACH PLATFORM
  with:
      registry: quay.io [THIS HAVE TO CHANGE BASED ON PLATFORM]
      username: ${{ secrets.USER }}
      password: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
```

Comment: As an example, like I mentioned registry needs to change based on the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use [ternary operator](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#example) to choose the `registry` variable value depending upon the platform you are running the job. ie,

```
- uses: docker/login-action@v2
  with:
      registry: ${{ (runner.os == 'Linux' && 'LinuxValue') || (runner.os == 'macOS' && 'MacOSValue' || 'WindowsValue') }}
      username: ${{ secrets.USER }}
      password: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
```

In the expression,

```
${{ (runner.os == 'Linux' && 'LinuxValue') || (runner.os == 'macOS' && 'MacOSValue' || 'WindowsValue')
```

The [`runner.os` returns the operating system of the `runner` executing the job. Possible values are *Linux*, *Windows*, or *macOS*.](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#runner-context)

We are checking if `runner.os == 'Linux'`, if it's the `registry` variable will be set to `LinuxValue`. if not the second part of the expression(`runner.os == 'macOS' && 'MacOSValue' || 'WindowsValue'`) will be executed. This will again check if the os is `macOS` if yes, the `registry` variable will be set to `MacOSValue` otherwise `WindowsValue`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, will it work in this scenario?
-uses: actions/build-and-publish@v4
  with:
     context: ${{ ( platform == 'linux/amd64' && 'VALUE' ) || ( platform == 'linux/arm64' && 'VALUE') }}
     platforms: linux/amd64, linux/arm64